# Behaviour of callstack and this during .defineProperty method

Tags: javascript, object, properties, this, callstack

### Pre-face:

> Feel free to skip to the actual question below, if you find the
> 'backstory' here unnecessary. But I do believe it adds good amount of
> detail and further context for the question

Recently I've been experimenting with objects and the `[[ Prototype ]]` chain a little,

First, I was baffled as to why my `this` reference returned in a `NaN` with the following code:

```js
var obj = {
  a: 2
}

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'b', {
  value: this.a + 2,
  enumerable: true
});

console.log(obj.b);
```

First, I was baffled as to why, but then an occurance hit me of the `NaN` behaviour.
My `obj.b` is calculated as `undefined + 2`, hence returning in `NaN`

Now, obviously changing the code do explicit reference of `value: obj.a + 2` will do the trick, but I wanted to investigate further as to why `this.a` returns as `undefined`.

---

Basically, my issue was that the my callstack was referencing `Object.prototype.a`, because `Object.defineProperty` is implicity delegated `Object.prototype.defineProperty`.

So, explicity setting `a` as a property of the `Object.prototype` would fix the issue:

```js
var obj = {
  a: 2
}

Object.prototype.a = obj.a;

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'b', {
  value: this.a + 2,
  enumerable: true
});

console.log(obj.b);
```

This returns the expected result of `4` *(although yes, creating a property `a` to entire `Object.prototype` is definitely not the best programming practice, but for illustration purposes it will serve just fine)*

### The question:

However, what confuses me is, if I run a `console.trace` on the expression, my call-stack consists purely of `(anonymous)` - so basically the `global` (default) implicit binding for `this` keyword.

> You will have to run the code in your own console, as sadly `console.trace()` is unfortunately not supported by jsfiddle (least to my knowledge)

```
var obj = {
  a: 2
}

Object.prototype.a = obj.a;

console.trace(Object.defineProperty(obj, 'b', {
  value: this.a + 2,
  enumerable: true
}));
```

[image]

---

### TL/DR:

So to sum this question up into two quick bulletpoints:

1. Why does call-stack return only `(anonymous)` and not also `Object.prototype`
2. What would be the proper way to explicitly bind `this` to the referenced object `obj` in our `.defineProperty()` method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1) Why console.trace returns only (anonymous)

This behaviour should become apparent once you realise that you were using console.trace() incorrectly. If you go to Mozilla's manuals and look up console.trace() you will see that it is supposed to be used like this:

```
function foo() {
  function bar() {
    console.trace();
  }
  bar();
}

foo();
```

Which gives the following output:

```
bar
foo
<anonymous>
```

In other words, you have to call console.trace() *from within* some function rather than wrap a function call with it. That's because console.trace() first checks the name of the function from which it was called (**bar**), then the name of the parent invoking function (**foo**), then the name of its parent, and so on until it hits the outermost execution context, which is an **anonymous** function - the main execution thread, where all code begins.

Whenever you execute some code inside devtools (which is what I assume you are using), it is always executed in this global execution context, in the form of a wrapping anonymous function. Since you call console.trace() immediately from this anonymous function, this is what is printed - *anonymous*.

Also, console.trace() takes parameters. When you invoke console.trace(), you can use any number of arguments and these arguments are simply printed to the console just before the stack trace. Since Object.defineProperty() returns the object for which you are defining a new property, this is what you pass to console.trace().

**TL;DR** - console.trace() first prints it's arguments to the console (i.e. **obj**, which is {a: 2, b: 4}); it then proceeds to print the stack trace, which only consists of the main execution context, which is an anonymous function when you call your code from the console.

### 2) this, defineProperty and all that

The third argument to Object.defineProperty is a simple object, **not a function**! It's properties are resolved immediately during initialisation and only then is it passed into defineProperty. This means that the below is functionally identical to your code:

```
// First we initialize the third argument, separately from the call
// to .defineProperty()

var descriptor = {
  value: this.a + 2,
  enumerable: true
};

// at this point descriptor is already constructed. If you do
// console.log(descriptor.value) here, you will get NaN or maybe
// 4 or something else, depending on what you did before

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'b', descriptor);
// Here we simply invoke .defineProperty with descriptor as the third argument.
```

You also have to know that when you run code in the main execution context (e.g. code is called from the devtools console), **this** refers to the **Window** object. Window does not have a property a, which is why this.a is undefined.

What is more interesting is that this.a (or window.a) becomes 2 after you do Object.prototype.a = 2. This happens because Window is still an **Object**, after all. If you assign some property to the **prototype of the Object *object*** (!!!), you will have this property available on all objects in your code! Confusing? Yes! For now suffice it to say that what you intended to do (based on your description) was probably this:

```
obj.prototype = {a: 2};
```

or this:

```
var proto = {}; // First create a prototype
obj.prototype = proto; // Then assign it to the prototype property of your obj
obj.prototype.a = 2; // Now we can alter props on the prototype
```

See the difference? Does that make more sense? Of course, after you do this, your code will no longer work, because this.a will become undefined again.

The outcome is as follows: going this way you **cannot** achieve the behaviour you expect. Property descriptors (argument #3) are actually way more powerful than just a combination of *value* and *enumerable*, and you should be able to get your desired behaviour if you implemented set() & get() methods on it. Also, I believe you could use Proxies to get a similar behaviour. Not providing more details as I instead suggest you to read about function execution contexts first, then a little more on prototypes and maybe some good questions on stack overflow about the behaviour of **this**. After that you could try looking into the proposed solutions.